# Aligment of slur after cbreath

Tags: musixtex

It is required to align the slur after cbreath command, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %\systemnumbers
    %1er compás
    \NOtes
    \zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.4cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 13}}}
    \wh d\hsk\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu e\tslur0f\hu f\qsk\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\hu f\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes\wh f\hsk\en\bar
    %5to compás
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu e\tslur0d\hu d\qsk\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\wh c\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %7mo compás
    \NOtes\islurd0d\hu d\tslur0c\hu c\qsk\en\bar
    %8vo compás
    \NOtes\islurd0d\hu d\tslur0e\hu e\qsk\en
    %\systemnumbers
    \alaligne%\bar
    %1er compás
    \NOtes\hu d\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\islurd0e\wh e\hsk\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\tslur0d\wh d\hsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes
    \raisebox{2pt}{\hspace*{-0.8cm} \cbreath}
    \islurd0e\hu e\hu f\hsk\en\bar
    %5to compás
    \NOtes\tslur0d\hu d\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\islurd0e\wh e\hsk\en\bar
    %7mo compás
    \NOtes\wh d\hsk\en\bar
    %8vo compás
    \NOtes\tslur0c\wh c\hsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output should be as follow (note that is needed horizontal aligment of slur):
[image: desired]

Comment: Some time ago I advised you to eliminate all, really all, unnecessary spaces in your typesettings. This is told in the MusiXTeX manual as well. Therefore I downvote your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!! Instead of: \raisebox{2pt}{\hspace*{-0.8cm} \cbreath}, just use:
\loffset{3.0}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.13cm} \cbreath}}
The code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %\systemnumbers
    %1er compás
    \NOtes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.4cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 13}}}\wh d\hsk\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu e\tslur0f\hu f\qsk\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\hu f\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes\wh f\hsk\en\bar
    %5to compás
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu e\tslur0d\hu d\qsk\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\wh c\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %7mo compás
    \NOtes\islurd0d\hu d\tslur0c\hu c\qsk\en\bar
    %8vo compás
    \NOtes\islurd0d\hu d\tslur0e\hu e\qsk\en
    %\systemnumbers
    \alaligne%\bar
    %1er compás
    \NOtes\hu d\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\islurd0e\wh e\hsk\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\tslur0d\wh d\hsk\loffset{3.0}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.13cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    %\loffset{5.0}{\raisebox{2pt}{\hspace*{0.6cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu e\hu f\hsk\en\bar
    %5to compás
    \NOtes\tslur0d\hu d\hp\qsk\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\islurd0e\wh e\hsk\en\bar
    %7mo compás
    \NOtes\wh d\hsk\en\bar
    %8vo compás
    \NOtes\tslur0c\wh c\hsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: The initiation of the slur has not been influenced by the \raisebox or other things you did with the \cbreath, but by the spaces you deleted by having it now followed by \en\bar (and the other changes you made around that bar).